# AS3 Add movieclip to the stage on the Y axis between two points

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I am trying to add a caveman (in an android game I am making for uni) on perticular X axis which is easy but the caveman is spawning anywhere on that Y axis and I would like it to spawn just in between to points that I specify on the Y axis.

```
cavemanVar[2].x = 352.10;
cavemanVar[2].y = Math.random()*300;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the start position `a` plus a random value whose max would be the difference to make up `b`.

```
y = a + Math.random() * (b - a);
```

Visually:

```
--+--  <- a
  |
  |
  |    <- Math.random() * (b - a)
  |
  |
--+--  <- b
```

Comment: thanks, its simple and it worked. I did try `y = 260.80 + Math.random()*100;` but obviously didn't work. Thanks for the speedy answer and ill accept it when it allows me to lol